# Understanding elasticsearch logs: Bad news present, but not good news

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch 1.7.2 on CentOS

Issue: Cluster went from green status to off green (not sure yellow or red, we just alert when status <> green), and then back to green by itself.

Elasticsearch log:

```
[2015-11-20 18:11:50,750][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [node-6a] [index_v6][1] received shard failed for [index_v6][1], node[rNAaZCFtTv6cG1eMP30b9g], [R], s[INITIALIZING], unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2015-11-20T18:11:42.859Z], details[shard failure [engine failure, reason [out of memory (source: [index])]][OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space]]]], indexUUID [4lNodBboRoep64nAfxXbeQ], reason [shard failure [failed to create shard][IndexShardCreationException[[index_v6][1] failed to create shard]; nested: LockObtainFailedException[Can't lock shard [index_v6][1], timed out after 5000ms]; ]]
[2015-11-20 18:14:34,074][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [node-6a] [index_v6][2] received shard failed for [index_v6][2], node[ur-Fm7iCSYSemcHWLTgIVA], [R], s[INITIALIZING], unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2015-11-20T18:03:56.528Z], details[shard failure [engine failure, reason [already closed by tragic event]][OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space]]]], indexUUID [4lNodBboRoep64nAfxXbeQ], reason [shard failure [failed recovery][RecoveryFailedException[[index_v6][2]: Recovery failed from [node-6a][rNAaZCFtTv6cG1eMP30b9g][elastic-search-6a][inet[/10.#########:9300]]{master=true} into [node-6b][ur-Fm7iCSYSemcHWLTgIVA][elastic-search-6b][inet[/10.######:9300]]{master=true}]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[node-6a][inet[/10.#########:9300]][internal:index/shard/recovery/start_recovery]]; nested: RecoveryEngineException[[index_v6][2] Phase[1] Execution failed]; nested: RecoverFilesRecoveryException[[index_v6][2] Failed to transfer [146] files with total size of [9.9gb]]; nested: SendRequestTransportException[[node-6b][inet[/10.######:9300]][internal:index/shard/recovery/file_chunk]]; nested: OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space]; ]]
```

We understand that we hit the java heap memory limit. We are used to that (unfortunately).

What we do not understand:

1) The cluster went back to green, but we see nothing in the logs to help us understand when or why.

2) We thought these config values might help:

```
indices.fielddata.cache.size:  75%
indices.breaker.fielddata.limit: 70%
```

But they seem to make no difference.

(We are still in process of moving to doc values, etc.)